# construct a sequences of integrable function that tends to the dirichlet function.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, real-numbers

so I wanted to ask if (it is even possible) to construct a sequence of integrable function $f_n$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ where $f$ is the dirichlet function.

$f := \begin{cases}0\ \ x\in[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}\\1 \ x\in [a,b]\ \  \cap \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$

If it is possible, could someone show me how it is done. I just think that this might be a good counter-example to know for some of the true/false questions I have been facing in my course of studies.

Any help and insight is deeply appreciated.

Comment: What is the Dirichlet function?

Comment: Look up for "Baire function" classes (the parts about Baire Class 0 and Baire Class 1). How can you relate continuity with integrability? You might have an insight on it. I'm not entirely sure about this, but is the idea that I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{r_1,r_2,\ldots\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[a,b]$.  The following sequence of functions converges pointwise to the Dirichlet function:

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}1, x \in \{r_1,r_2,...,r_n\} \\ 0, x \in [a,b] \setminus \{r_1,r_2,...,r_n\} \end{cases}$$

Note that each $f_n$ is Riemann integrable since it is discontinuous on at most a (finite) set of measure $0$.

Comment: I see, this is really awesome. So we are sort of using the fact the rationals are countably infinite between [a,b] and lets each $f_n$ denotes the first n rationals and as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the set becomes the entire rationals on [a,b]. Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome.  As an aside, Baires Theorem excludes the possibility of finding a sequence of continuous functions converging to the Dirichlet function. However it can be realized as the limit of a double sequence of continuous functions. For example on $[0,1]$ we have $f(x) = \lim_{j \to \infty} \lim_{k \to \infty} (\cos j! \pi x)^k$.